# Promise is not a function?

Tags: node.js, es6-promise

I'm getting a pretty standard error that I *should* be able to figure out but I am stuck like chuck ATM:

first_query(): TypeError: ind_promise is not a function

I have simplified the code down to its very basic core components and I cannot shake this error.

```
router.get('/:cusId/email/start', auth.check, async (req, res) => {

    try {

        let cus_id = req.params.cusId;

        const pool = await poolPromise;
        let query;
        let request;

        query = ("SELECT (CUS_FIRST_NAME + ' ' + CUS_LAST_NAME) AS CUS_NAME, CUS_IND_ID FROM CUS WHERE CUS_STATUS = 'A' AND CUS_ID = @CUS_ID");

        request = pool.request()
            .input('CUS_ID', sql.Int, cus_id);

        std.first_query(request, query)

            .then(async function(cus_rec) {

                let ind_promise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {

                    resolve (1);

                });

                ind_promise()

                    .then((ind_id) => {

                      console.log(ind_id);

                    })

                    .catch((err) => {

                        console.log('ind_promise(): ' + err.message);
                        res.status(500);
                        res.send(err.message)

                    });

            })

            .catch (function(err) {

                console.log('first_query(): ' + err);
                res.status(500);
                res.send(err.message)

            });

    } catch {

        console.log(err.message);
        res.status(500);
        res.send(err.message)

    }

});
```

This is more than a little irritating as I am not new to promises.  I know I am doing something very stupid but it's not obvious.  Experts, please help.

Comment: Change this `ind_promise().then` to this `ind_promise.then`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You called your promise right away and then you tried to invoke it like its a function

```
let ind_promise = new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {resolve (1);});
ind_promise()
```

Either change `ind_promise` to be a function, or call it without invoking it `ind_promise.then`

Comment: @Nick Stuff happens to all of us :)